# ViewDoesNotExist at / . Django weird error

Tags: python, django

I am coming across this issue for the first time, and it is very confusing. I just set up new django project like i do >10 times. but this time somehow, once i start the project and open the localhost, i am getting the weird error:

```
ViewDoesNotExist at /
Could not import avicenna.home.views. Parent module avicenna.home does not exist.
```

avicenna is my project name. and home is the app name..

this is my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url(r'^$', 'avicenna.home.views', name='home'),
  url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

this is my view:

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def home(request):
   return render_to_response('index.html',{},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

what can be wrong here? this is the structure of project

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably you need to change this:

```
url(r'^$', 'avicenna.home.views', name='home'),
```

with

```
url(r'^$', 'home.views.home', name='home'),
```

so, based on your updated post: linking to `avicenna.home.views` isn't enough, you need to tell which view you're referencing to. In alternative, change your url patterns like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('home.views',
  url(r'^$', 'home', name='home'),
  url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

but in any case, you need to tell django what view should be called for each url pattern. Also, `manage.py` is already inside your `avicenna` app; if you type `avicenna.home...`, django looks for a `home` module inside your 3rd avicenna folder, but you want it to look for views inside your bare `home` module.

Not sure this completely solves your problem, though, there seems to be something else (is `home` registered in your installed apps?)

Comment: i changed but the same error message with swapped letters: 
``Could not import avicenna.views.home. Parent module avicenna.views does not exist.``

Comment: post your folder/files structure then, plz. also, do you have a `__init__.py` inside `avicenna`?

Comment: You need a ``__init__.py`` file in your ``home`` directory. Sorry just noticed you have one.

Comment: i solved it. avicenna was a wrong name. i need the app name and not project name in urls.py for navigation. thanks for help anyway :)

Comment: oh boy :) well, I'm glad you realized it (you still have it in my answer if you want!)